# Can I use NFC demo as a tester of foreground dispatch?

Tags: android, nfc

I tried NFC demo with my nexus s and it works well.
I want to call an app from background to foreground using foregrounddispatch example given by android sdk. Can I test foregrounddispatch example with NFC demo? Does anyone who tried this?
and if possible, which part I should edit? It is my first time to manage android app so please give me advice.

(foregrounddispatch example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/nfc/ForegroundDispatch.html )

Answer (score 0):

Foreground dispatching requires the app to be in the foreground when scanning the tag. If I understand correctly, you want an app to launch upon scanning the tag. In this case, you need to create intent filters to handle the specific tag that you want to handle. See the dev guide for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html or let me know if you need more guidance.